# Value of vector not being modified by function

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've just started learning unity, and I'm struggling on a rather silly problem but which I can't seem to fix.

I have a simple function which is meant to look at components of a vector and resize them to the maximum allowed, if they are above a certain threshold.

Unfortunately, it dones't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```cs
public class HumanController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rBody;
    Vector3 currSpeed;
    Vector3 currAcceleration;

    Vector3 dt = new Vector3(0.03333f, 0.03333f, 0.03333f);
    public const float MAX_COMPONENT_ACCELERATION = 1;
    public const float MAX_COMPONENT_SPEED = 5;

    Logger logger = new Logger(new MyLogHandler());

    void EnsureVectorLimit(Vector3 vector, float limit)
    {
        if (vector.x > limit)
            vector.x = limit;
        else if (vector.x < -limit)
            vector.x = -limit;

        if (vector.y > limit)
            vector.y = limit;
        else if (vector.y < -limit)
            vector.y = -limit;

        if (vector.z > limit)
            vector.z = limit;
        else if (vector.z < -limit)
            vector.z = -limit;
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        var horz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Rescale 
        currAcceleration += Vector3.Scale(new Vector3(horz, 0, vert), dt);
        EnsureVectorLimit(currAcceleration, MAX_COMPONENT_ACCELERATION);

        logger.Log($"Current acceleration: {currAcceleration.ToString()}");


        currSpeed += Vector3.Scale(currAcceleration, dt);
        EnsureVectorLimit(currSpeed, MAX_COMPONENT_SPEED);

        rBody.transform.Translate(currSpeed);
    }
}
```

Yet the values in the "current acceleration" log are not bounded by the expected limit of 1, but seem to go arbitrarily high/low.

Could someone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You can use [`Vector3.ClampMagnitude()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html) if that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a struct (like Vector3) into a function, the original struct does not get modified. You should use the `ref` keyword, which allows you to pass a reference instead:

Replace

```
void EnsureVectorLimit(Vector3 vector, float limit)
```

with

```
void EnsureVectorLimit(ref Vector3 vector, float limit)
```

and

```
EnsureVectorLimit(currAcceleration, MAX_COMPONENT_ACCELERATION);
```

with

```
EnsureVectorLimit(ref currAcceleration, MAX_COMPONENT_ACCELERATION);
```

This insures, that the Vector3 you modify is the same Vector3 you passed into the function

`ref` works like `pointer`, it sends memory location instead of just value, so you can not only read but also modify it.

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't realise it was a `struct`.. so if it had been a class, it would've worked without the ref right?

Comment: In this case yes